# Center text in tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'am using tikz to draw a simple threshold logic unit.

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{basic/.style={draw,fill=blue!20,text width=1em,text badly centered}}
\tikzset{functions/.style={basic,circle,fill=blue!10}}
%\tikzset{inputs/.style={basic,circle,fill=blue!20}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}


\node (center) {y};
\node[functions,left=3em of center, anchor=center] (left) {\scriptsize $\theta$=5};
\path[draw,->] (left) -- (center);
            
            
\node[left=3em of left] (l2) {};
  
        
\node[below of=l2] (n) {$x_2$};
\path[draw,->] (n) -- node[below, rotate=34] {\scriptsize $\omega_2=4$} (left);
  
            
\node[above of=l2] (1) {$x_1$};
\path[draw,->] (1) -- node[above, rotate=-34] {\scriptsize $\omega_1=3$} (left);
 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This generates the following output:

[image]

As you can see the text in the node is not centered. I tried`text centered` and `align=center` and I triedto adjust the size of the node by using `minimum width=8mm, inner sep=0mm,`.

How can I adjust the text to be exactly centered? I believe the math mode makes trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text is actually centered, so it's not a problem of alignment, but a problem of `\textwidth`, if you remove it, the circle node can adapt to the content and, there you go, it's centered.

My suggestion is to remove `text width=1em` or increase its value from the style.

Here you can see what I mean:

[image]

and this is the code:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{basic/.style={draw,fill=blue!20,text width=1em}}
\tikzset{functions/.style={basic,circle,fill=blue!10}}
%\tikzset{inputs/.style={basic,circle,fill=blue!20}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[functions, anchor=center] (left) {\scriptsize $\theta$=5};

\node[functions,above=3em of left, anchor=center, text width=% resets the text width
] (left) {\scriptsize $\theta$=5};
            
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You'r right.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is already described in @Alenanno answer, i.e. your text in node `function` is wider than prescribed text width - consequently it spill-out on the right side of node. Solution is (ii) prescribe wider `text width` in `basic` node or (ii) not use `basic` in definition of the `function` style, as is done in suggested MWE below. In it are proposed mostly off topic suggestions:

- used are syntax defined in the library `positioning`
- style `function` is defined independent from `basic`
- for edge labels is used `quotes` library
- for is drawn from node `function`

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,
                quotes}

\tikzset{basic/.style = {draw,fill=blue!20, inner sep=1pt,
                         minimum width=1em, align=center},
     functions/.style = {basic,circle,fill=blue!10, font=\scriptsize},
every edge/.append style = {->},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, inner sep=1pt, font=\scriptsize, sloped}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance =1.5em and 3em
                        ]
\node[functions] (f) {$\theta$=5};
\node[above left=of f] (x1) {$x_1$};
\node[below left=of f] (x2) {$x_2$};
\node[right=of f]       (y)     {$y$};
%
\path   (x1) edge ["$\omega_1=3$"]      (f) 
        (x2) edge ["$\omega_2=4$" ']    (f)
        (f)  edge   (y);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]